# Salesforce send Outbound Message as PUT

Tags: salesforce

I am sending outbound messages from Salesforce.  They are always sending as POST, though.  Is there a way to change the method they are using?

I'd like to send some of them as PUT, instead (and, eventually, some DELETE).  I'm not finding anything from Google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outbound Messages are SOAP 1.1 based, and as such are required to use POST by the SOAP 1.1 spec, so there are no options to use other HTTP methods for the Outbound Message requests.

If you want to send HTTP requests instead of SOAP messages, you'll need to write an Apex trigger and use a future method to make the HTTP request from apex.